# How to render a timestamp from Firestore

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

[Here is a picture of the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Fi4T.png) When I try to render my timestamp from firestore it shows an error
"Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {seconds, nanoseconds}. If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead." How do I format my code to display my timestamp from the Firestore. I am able to create the timestamp and read it in my firestore dashboard.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
 StyleSheet,
 ScrollView,
 ActivityIndicator,
 View,
 Text,
} from "react-native";
import { List, NativeBaseProvider } from "native-base";
import { ListItem } from "react-native-elements";
import colors from "../config/colors";

import firebase from "../../firebase";

class SearchEntry extends Component {
 constructor() {
  super();
this.firestoreRef =        firebase.firestore().collection("RepairDocuments");
this.state = {
  isLoading: true,
  entryArr: [],
 };
}
componentDidMount() {
this.unsubscribe =       this.firestoreRef.onSnapshot(this.getCollection);
}
componentWillUnmount() {
 this.unsubscribe();
}
getCollection = (querySnapshot) => {
 const entryArr = [];
 querySnapshot.forEach((res) => {
  const { unit, datetime, bio } = res.data();
  entryArr.push({
    key: res.id,
    res,
    unit,
    datetime,
    bio,
  });
});
this.setState({
  entryArr,
  isLoading: false,
});
};
render() {
  if (this.state.isLoading) {
    return (
     <View style={styles.preloader}>
      <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#9E9E9E" />
     </View>
   );
}
return (
  <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
    {this.state.entryArr.map((res, i) => {
      return (
        <ListItem
          key={i}
          onPress={() => {
            this.props.navigation.navigate("Details", {
              userkey: res.key,
            });
          }}
          bottomDivider
        >
          <ListItem.Content>
            <ListItem.Title>{res.unit}</ListItem.Title>
            <ListItem.Subtitle>{new Date(res.datetime?.unixTime * 1000).toLocaleDateString(
                ""
              )}</ListItem.Subtitle>
          </ListItem.Content>
          <ListItem.Chevron color="black" />
        </ListItem>
      );
    })}
  </ScrollView>
 );
}
}
```

Here is the code that enters the time stamp to my firestore.

```
import React, { Component, useState } from       "react";
import {
  ImageBackground,
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Image,
  ActivityIndicator,
  Text,
} from "react-native";
import LargeButton      from"  .. /  components   /LargeButton";
import colors from "../config/colors";
import firebase from "../../firebase";
import DatePicker from "@react-native-     community/datetimepicker";

class CreateEntry extends Component {
 constructor() {
 super();
  this.dbRef =    firebase.firestore().collection("RepairDocuments");

 this.state = {
  unit: "",
  datetime: new Date(),
  bio: "",
  isLoading: false,
};
}

 onChange = (event, selectedDate) => {
   const showFlag = Platform.OS === "ios";
   this.setState({ show: showFlag });
    this.inputValueUpdate(selectedDate,   "datetime");
  };

  inputValueUpdate = (val, prop) => {
  const state = this.state;
  state[prop] = val;
  this.setState(state);
  };
  storeEntry() {
   if (this.state.unit === "") {
    alert("Please fill out unit #");
   } else {
  this.setState({
    isLoading: true,
  });
  this.dbRef
    .add({
      unit: this.state.unit,
      datetime: this.state.datetime,
      bio: this.state.bio,
    })
    .then((res) => {
      this.setState({
        unit: "",
        datetime: new Date(),
        bio: "",
        isLoading: false,
      });
      this.props.navigation.navigate("Home");
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error("Error found: ", err);
      this.setState({
        isLoading: false,
      });
      });
      }
      }

    render() {
     if (this.state.isLoading) {
     return (
       <View style={styles.preloader}>
        <ActivityIndicator size="large"  color="#9E9E9E" />
      </View>
     );
    showMode = (currentMode) => {
    this.setState({ show: true });
    this.setState({ mode: currentMode });
  };
  showDatepicker = () => {
    this.showMode("date");
  };
}

return (
  <ImageBackground
    style={styles.background}
    source={require("../assets/Login.jpeg")}
  >
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.header}>
        <Image
          style={styles.headerLogo}
          source={require("../assets/WordLogo.jpeg")}
        />
      </View>

      <View style={styles.inputGroup}>
        <TextInput
          placeholder={"Enter Unit #"}
          value={this.state.unit}
          onChangeText={(val) => this.inputValueUpdate(val, "unit")}
        />
      </View>

      <View style={styles.inputGroup}>
        <Text>Select Date:</Text>
        <View>
          <DatePicker
            testID="dateTimePicker"
            value={this.state.datetime}
            display="default"
            onChange={this.onChange}
            dateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy h:mm aa"
          />
        </View>
      </View>

      <View style={styles.inputGroup}>
        <TextInput
          placeholder={"Enter Work Completed"}
          value={this.state.bio}
          onChangeText={(val) => this.inputValueUpdate(val, "bio")}
        />
      </View>

      <LargeButton
        title="submit"
        color="secondary"
        onPress={() => this.storeEntry()}
      />
    </View>
  </ImageBackground>
);
```

}
}

Comment: Have you looked at the [toDate](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.Timestamp#todate) method on the Timestamp object? It will convert it to a JS date which is easier to manipulate and display (e.g. date `.toString` method).

Comment: Yes I tired using the it like this {res.datetime.toDate()} and it say "undefined is not an object (evaluating 'res.datetime.toDate')

Comment: The firestore data may not have loaded, could you try `{res.datetime ? res.datetime.toDate() : ""}` instead?

Comment: Okay. The error has changes to "Objects are not valid as a React Child (found: Thu Mar 31 2022 23:07:26 GMT-0500 (CDT)). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead. "

Comment: Please check updated code and picture. The subtitle displays "Invalid Date"

Comment: What happens if you print it the data you are trying to display to the console?

Comment: It will show like this 2022-04-30T05:00:00.000Z. I really don't understand why this isn't working. I've now added my code where I passing the date to the firestore

Comment: And when console.log(res.datetime) it displays Object {
  "nanoseconds": 0,
  "seconds": 1649298480,
}